# root level css in angular 2 with webpack for JS disabled

Tags: angular, webpack

I am attempting to create a javascript disabled page off of my index html.

```
// index.html

<noscript>
  <div class="noJS">
    <h2>You must have JavaScript enabled to log in.</h2>
  </div>
</noscript>
```

All in all there will be enough styling on this that I do not want to keep it in the html file. *The problem was that because js is disabled, we can not use any imports because, well, javascript is disabled. Because js is disabled, webpack did not build/move that .css file to the root directory.*

I have tried to create a new .css file and import it in the index.html. However, I am using webpack and webpack is not generating this .css file to the "server" it creates.

***EDIT***
 - I have added it as a LoaderOptionsPlugin via the html loader.

```
// webpack.dev.js

htmlLoader: {
  ignoreCustomFragments: [/\{\{.*?}}/],
  root: path.resolve(__dirname, '/src'),
  attrs: ['link:href']
}
```

If you guys have any suggestions, I would greatly appreciate it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I actually got this working, I was able to copy the file over in webpack using the following code for anyone that may want that.

```
// webpack.common.js

new CopyWebpackPlugin([
  {
    from: 'src/assets',
    to: 'src/assets',
  }, {
    from: 'web.config',
    to: 'web.config'
  }, {
    from: 'src/no-js.css',
    to: 'no-js.css'
  }
])
```